# How to fix transport error in "IBM toolkit EGit plugin clone repository" option

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I am using IBM toolkit v 10.0.0.7 and I have installed EGit plugin from eclipse market place according to required version configurations. Installed EGit plugin successfully and I am able to see the option "Git" in perspective.

When I tried to clone a repository from our on premise GitLab project, After providing required information such as URL, credentials and click Next. It gives me Transport error in the branch selection window as below.

```
Transport Error:

An error occurred while trying to contact https://git.repo/iib_test.git
See the error Log for details

Possible reasons:
     -Incorrect URL
     -No network connection (e.g. wrong proxy settings)
     -SSL host could not be verified (set http.sslVerify=false in Git configuration)
```

I have git bash installed in the same machine. I have tried to clone with git bash and I was able to clone the GitLab repository without any error.

I have tried to open the already cloned git repository from IBM toolkit Git perspective window. I was able browse the repository and see the branches and versions. I have also tried to change a file and commit using Egit plugin perspective and I was able to commit as well. But when I tried push to remote then it throws me the same error as when tried to clone.

Error log is like below:

```js
Severity: Error
Message: https://mygit.xxx.com/iib_test/pim_test.git: cannot open git-upload-pack

Exception Stack Trace:

org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: https://mygit.xxxxx.com/iib_test/pim_test.git: cannot open git-upload-pack
 at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.execute(LsRemoteCommand.java:221)
 at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.call(LsRemoteCommand.java:159)
 at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.ListRemoteOperation.run(ListRemoteOperation.java:100)
 at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.clone.SourceBranchPage$8.run(SourceBranchPage.java:341)
 at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: https://mygit.xxxx.com/iib_test/pim_test.git: cannot open git-upload-pack
 at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.connect(TransportHttp.java:527)
 at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.openFetch(TransportHttp.java:290)
 at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.execute(LsRemoteCommand.java:198)
 ... 4 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:208)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:134)
 at com.ibm.jsse2.a.a(a.java:227)
 at com.ibm.jsse2.a.a(a.java:269)
 at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.a(qc.java:459)
 at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.h(qc.java:275)
 at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.a(qc.java:541)
 at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.startHandshake(qc.java:89)
 at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.c.afterConnect(c.java:173)
 at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.d.connect(d.java:63)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1314)
 at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
 at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.b.getResponseCode(b.java:15)
 at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.http.JDKHttpConnection.getResponseCode(JDKHttpConnection.java:98)
 at org.eclipse.jgit.util.HttpSupport.response(HttpSupport.java:190)
 at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.connect(TransportHttp.java:465)
 ... 6 more
 
Session Data:

eclipse.buildId=4.2.2.M20140918-1444
java.fullversion=JRE 1.7.0 IBM J9 2.7 Windows 10 amd64-64 Compressed References 20160630_309914 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - R27_Java727_SR3_20160630_1516_B309914
JIT  - tr.r13.java_20160629_120282
GC   - R27_Java727_SR3_20160630_1516_B309914_CMPRSS
J9CL - 20160630_309914
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -showlocation -product com.ibm.etools.msgbroker.tooling.ide tools_auto -showlocation -product com.ibm.etools.msgbroker.tooling.ide
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -showlocation -product com.ibm.etools.msgbroker.tooling.ide tools_auto -showlocation -product com.ibm.etools.msgbroker.tooling.ide
```

It seems somehow the Egit is not making connection with GitLab project URL. We don't need proxy to connect our Gitlab server.

I have tried options such as disable ssl in git configurations and use http instead of https and none of them are working.

I would like to clone a git repository from IBM toolkit EGit perspective window using Https protocol only [ we don't use ssh for security reasons].

I would appreciate everyone's inputs in fixing this issue.

Thank you

Comment: Text is better than picture of text. Please re-insert the textual form of the shown information.

Comment: Does your Gitlab server use a self signed SSL certificate? You can easily check this by opening it in your browser and check who the CA is, which issued the SSL certificate.

Comment: We use Comodo RSA certificate not the self signed  certificate.

Comment: Q: Do you happen to have any `iib_test` (presumably "IBM Integration Bus") anywhere in your environment?

Comment: I am using IBM integration toolkit and to use Git, I have installed EGit plugin. So far no such environment configurations that I know off. I am just trying to clone a repo name by iib_test.git.